# Why we use TRUE in load a view in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

Controller:

```
$data = array();
$page['left_content'] = $this->load->view('left_content', $data, TRUE);
$page['main_content'] = $this->load->view('left_content', $data, TRUE);
$page['right_content'] = $this->load->view('left_content', $data, TRUE);
$this->load->view('home',$data);
```

View:

```
<body>
<?php if(isset($left_content)){echo $left_content;}?>
<?php if(isset($main_content)){echo $main_content;}?>
<?php if(isset($right_content)){echo $right_content;}?>
</body>
```

Please take look to above code. This code is used to view a page in main homepage. 
Now just take a test. If we just remove TRUE from code the code does not work properly. That means when we remove it then the view does not prints itself at its right place. it prints itself at the top of the main view or main home page.
I have googled a lot but can not find any cause to use it.
I just want to know why we just use TRUE in this code? thnx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When we pass TRUE as optional parameter while loading view, it returns the content rather than sending(displaying) data to browser directly.

You can check in [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html#footer):

> There is a third optional parameter lets you change the behavior of
>   the function so that it returns data as a string rather than sending
>   it to your browser. This can be useful if you want to process the data
>   in some way. If you set the parameter to true (boolean) it will return
>   data. The default behavior is false, which sends it to your browser.
>   Remember to assign it to a variable if you want the data returned:
>
> $string = $this->load->view('myfile', '', true);

Comment: i guess it is same; `ob_start();
$this->load->view("some_view");
$echoed_content = ob_get_clean();`

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of third optional parameter lets you change the behavior of the function so that it returns data as a string rather than sending it to your browser. it is very useful if you want to process the data in some way. If you set the parameter to true (boolean) it will return data. The default behavior is false, which sends it to your browser.

Example :

```
$dataString = $this->load->view('viewFileName','', true);
```

NOTE : Remember to assign it to a variable if you want the data returned

Here $dataString variable contains data as string of requested view file [Read here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html) for more detail